# Find first and last dates of quarter from system date SQL query including quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a table as shown here from SQL Server based on run date (run date is system date - today 01/08/2022):

| Start date | End date | Quarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2021 | 12/31/2021 | 2021Q4 |

Comment: Not clear.  Are you looking for the prior quarter from the current date?

Comment: Should today have been 01/08/2022?

Comment: yes, I need prior quarter information to feed my table for prior calculation.

Comment: You should [create a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) and just pre-populate it one time because [calculating it all the time is tedious](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f9806a542e9e8849625308f64cbd388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.   However, Aaron is 100% correct in suggesting a calendar table.

```
Select *
      ,[Quarter] = datename(year,StartDate)+'Q'+datename(quarter,StartDate)
 From  (values (dateadd(QUARTER, datediff(QUARTER, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
               ,dateadd(DAY, -1, dateadd(QUARTER, datediff(QUARTER, 0, getdate()), 0)))
       )A(StartDate,EndDate)
```

Retults

```
StartDate   EndDate     Quarter
2021-10-01  2021-12-31  2021Q4
```